# Salesforce OAuth flow - getting a new refresh token

Tags: oauth2, refresh-token, accesstoken

I have setup OpenID to use Salesforce as the IDP for an external site. We are using embedded login and server side callback flow.

I have a requirement to set the lifespan of the access token to 60 min and the refresh token to 120 min.

My question is once the access token expires after 60 min, we then need to use the refresh token to call for a new access token. The new access token will last 60 min, and at this point the refresh token will also last 60 min. What happens when both the access token and refresh token expire? There will be no refresh token to request a new access token. The user would have to re-authenticate and type in username/password again.

Is there a flow to get a refreshed refresh token?

Comment: Is this third-party site using the Salesforce APIs? If so, Salesforce is an SP, not an IDP. IDP means it asserts a user is a particular user, and it doesn't use tokens, so the rules for OAuth would be whatever the third-party site is configured for; in other words, this question would be off-topic here.

Comment: My terminology may be off - the third part site is using Salesforce API's. But on the Salesforce side we configure the connected app to have an access token expiration and a refresh token expiration. If our security teams mandate the refresh token cannot last more than 120 minutes, my question is how would that site retrieve a new access token once it expires? I'm not sure why this would be off topic. We have provided the team with a refresh token flow but now I'm wondering how to refresh the refresh token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot refresh an expired or revoked Refresh Token. It is used to refresh the user's access to Salesforce (the Access Token) if it expires, and a Refresh Token cannot be used to access any Salesforce API. Given your hypothetical example, once the user's Access Token expires, and the Refresh Token expires, they will be forced to log in again.

If the Refresh Token was instead set to Refresh Until Duration, having short-lived sessions would allow a user to refresh indefinitely until the Refresh Token expired from inactivity.

However, note that Access Tokens themselves automatically refresh if they are used in the second half of their Session Duration. In other words, given a 60 minute Access Token, it will automatically reset its Session Duration to 60 minutes if any API calls are made with 30 minutes remaining or less.

Comment: Thanks! This answers my question